# SQL Server ON DELETE and inheritance

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I have 3 tables: Notifications, NewItemNotifications and Items.
I've set an ON DELETE rule on the NewItemNotifications and Items table which deletes the NewItemNotification row when I delete some item.
The problem is that the parent row in the Notifications table is still exists, how can I handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewItemNotification` is dependent table - it can never trigger deletion of parent record through database constraint. The only way is to write a database trigger on `NewItemNotification` to perform delete in `Notification` table after the dependent record is deleted.

The problem is that such trigger can cause issue if EF will try to delete `NewItemNotification` because it doesn't know about trigger existence. It first deleted `NewItemNotification` record which trigger deletion of `Notification` item without EF to know it. EF will then try to delete `Notification` record again but the record was already deleted. I think it will result in concurrency exception.

The best option in this case is not using cascade delete and handle delete yourselves.